# Wordpress admin menu arrow (wp-menu-arrow)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I trying hide wp-menu-arrow in wordpress admin (backend) for active link and for hover link.

my code not work but i dont know why.

code:

```
#adminmenu li.wp-first-item.current a.wp-first-item .wp-menu-arrow,
#adminmenu li.wp-first-item.current a.wp-first-item .wp-menu-arrow div,
#adminmenu li.current a.current .wp-menu-arrow,
#adminmenu li.current a.current .wp-menu-arrow div,
#adminmenu li.wp-has-current-submenu a.wp-has-current-submenu .wp-menu-arrow,
#adminmenu li.wp-has-current-submenu a.wp-has-current-submenu .wp-menu-arrow div {display: none !important;}
```

can u help me ? thx

Comment: Can you share a snapshot of the wp-menu-arrow which you are trying to hide. In my local, by default it is with display:none !important

Comment: active link https://prnt.sc/wj78hn ...... hover link   https://prnt.sc/wj78vj .. thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
ul#adminmenu a.wp-has-current-submenu:after, ul#adminmenu>li.current>a.current:after{
    display:none;
    }
```

For Hover

[image]

```
#adminmenu li.wp-has-submenu.wp-not-current-submenu:hover:after{display:none}
```

Comment: Lovely ! Working ! Thanks a lot